# Load texture from code rather than MTL

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been able to load an OBJ file and associate an MTL to it to give it a texture. However I cannot seem to be able to tell what texture I want to associate with the model directly from the code, I can only get the texture to appear on the model if it is mentioned in the MTL file.

I looked at the documentations, I looked at the examples, and I googled over and over, but I just have no idea how to apply a texture.

This is my current code to load model and material file

```
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setPath( '/3Dproject/models/' );
        mtlLoader.load( 'tshirt.mtl', function( materials ) {

            materials.preload();

            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
            objLoader.setPath( 'models/' );
            objLoader.load( 'tshirt.obj', function ( object ) {

                object.position.x = 0;
                object.position.y = -50;
                object.scale.x = 2;
                object.scale.y = 2;
                object.scale.z = 2;
                scene.add( object );

            }, onProgress, onError );

        });
```

This is my material file

```
# MTL written from \3Dproject\models\tshirt.obj
newmtl texture
Kd 0.48 0.48 0.48
Ns 256
d 1
illum 2
Ka 0 0 0
Ks 0.04 0.04 0.04
map_Kd \texture.jpg
```

If I load my texture in the Javascript like this

```
        var texloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var skinTexture = texloader.load('/3Dproject/models/texture.jpg', function (tex) {
            skinTexture = tex;
        });
```

How can I then apply it to my model?

Working example at http://creativiii.com/3Dproject/old-index.html

Comment: You could find your object in THREE.Scene and rewrite its material.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a texture is assigned via the `material.map` property.

```
object.material.map = skinTexture;
```